# firebase not return the key?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a query that get post key in /Feed/, and then get the /posts/ by this keys.

```
    snapshot.forEach((subChild) => {
        var value = subChild.val();

        value = value.postID;

        var post = firebase.database().ref('/posts/' + value).orderByKey();

        promises.push(new Promise((res, rej) => {
            post.on('value', function(snapshot2) {

                console.log(snapshot2.val());

                res(snapshot2.val());
            });
        }));
    });


let postsArray = await Promise.all(promises);
            setPosts(prevPosts => {

                return [
                    ...prevPosts,  
                    ...Object.keys(postsArray).reverse().map(key => ({
                        key: key, ...postsArray[key] 
                    }))
                ];
```

it return objects like this:

```
{id: 2, img: "src/img.jpg", title: "some text", user: "username_01"}
```

I'd like firebase to return the post key too. What can I do?

```
posts
 |
 ----M5HMGsA3YyW_NJfSV (wanna this value in object too)
      |
      ----id: 2
      |
      ----img: src/img.jpg
      |
      ----title: some text
      |
      ----user: username_01
```

Answer (score 1):

A snapshot2 `key` is the property of `snapshot2` object, so you can easily access it like:

```
post.on('value', function(snapshot2) {
  console.log(snapshot2.key);
});
```

Now, as you need to merge this key to return response, you can simply do this using the [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) method like:

```
post.on('value', function(snapshot2) {
  var obj = Object.assign(snapshot2.val(), { _key: snapshot2.key });
  console.log( obj );
  res( obj );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the key like that:

```
snapshot2.key
```

If you want to place it to your object, you have to push that value too to your array.